# Difference between future continuous and simple

Tags: progressive-aspect, future-continuous

Any differences between these two sentences:

> 1. I hope it won't rain when we leave the church (the rain might begin as soon as we have left the church).
> 2. I hope it won't  be raining when we leave the church (means it could begin before we leave the church and may be  continue after).

Answer (score 1):

You've already summarised the difference between the two sentences. The first says you hope it won't start raining when you leave the church. The second says you hope it won't be raining when you leave the church.